# XPATH of node with multiple namespaces

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a XML file which has content with multiple namespaces at the same level.How Can i get the XPATH of a particular node inside the XML.My XM content is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeploymentConfiguration xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.aveva.com/AVEVA/NET/deployment/5000">
<InstallDir>c:\temp</InstallDir>
<DashBoardMSIPath>c:\temp</DashBoardMSIPath>
<InstallDir>c:\temp</InstallDir>
<DatabaseManager>
    <WorkhubDatabases>
        <WorkHubDatabaseConfiguration>
            <Server>Test</Server>
        </WorkHubDatabaseConfiguration>
    </WorkhubDatabases>
</DatabaseManager>
</DeploymentConfiguration>
```

Suppose i need to change the value of Server Node.What Should be the XPath of Server Node.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mistake the namespace definitions in the document for the namespace definitions in the API

Your XML defines 2 namespaces

- `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` with the prefix `i`
- `http://www.aveva.com/AVEVA/NET/deployment/5000` without a prefix

The XML parser resolves the namespace definitions any element node without a prefix is in the namespace `http://www.aveva.com/AVEVA/NET/deployment/5000` you can read the node names like:

```
{http://www.aveva.com/AVEVA/NET/deployment/5000}:Server
```

The XPath processor get's its own namespace definitions. In the most APIs a namespace resolver is available.

### PHP

In PHP you register the namespaces on the DOMXpath instance:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('av', 'http://www.aveva.com/AVEVA/NET/deployment/5000');
```

After the registration you can use the defined prefix in your XPath expressions:

```
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('/av:DeploymentConfiguration/av:DatabaseManager/av:WorkhubDatabases/av:WorkHubDatabaseConfiguration/av:Server');
```

### Javascript

In JavaScript it is the third Argument of evaluate():

```
var resolver = {
  namespaces : {
   'av' : 'http://www.aveva.com/AVEVA/NET/deployment/5000'
  }
  lookupNamespaceURI = function(prefix) {
    if (prefix == '') {
      return null;
    }
    return this.namespaces[prefix] || null;
  };
}

var nodes = document.evaluate(
  '/av:DeploymentConfiguration/av:DatabaseManager/av:WorkhubDatabases /av:WorkHubDatabaseConfiguration/av:Server',
  document,
  resolver,
  XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,
  null
);
```

### XSLT

In XSLT you define them like in any other XML

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:av="http://www.aveva.com/AVEVA/NET/deployment/5000">
  <!-- ... -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```